# Merge "Rows data" and "Range/selection" data as Mail body in VBA using Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, merge, outlook

I am new to VBA, Ron de Bruin content have been a great help but I'm stuck with this problem. From Ron de Bruin's topic: How can I merge "Mail a row or rows to each person in a range" & " Mail Range/Selection in the body of the mail" so I can send it as HTML mail body using outlook?

I've looked everywhere but cannot find an answer to it, and my VBA knowledge limits the finding.

I used the same code from Ron de Bruin:
Mail Range/Selection in the body of the mail: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail8.htm

Mail Range/Selection in the body of the mail: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

What I did a bit was:

```
.HTMLBody =  RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & _
        "Find below the Absolute goal and its weightage:" & "<br>" & _
        Sheets("Sheet6").Range("M1:P12").Value & "<br><br><br>" & _
        "Regards," & "<br>" & _
        "XXXXX" & "<br>"
```

The email body comes blank.

I am looking for something like:

```
hello XX,
Please find below the performance details:
Login ID    Agent                 TM    Handles Count 
XXXX             asdsd@gmail.com      yyy   1234         4567

Find below the absolute goals:

Skill   metric  handles  count
ggggg   hhhhh   23465    77777

Regards,
ddddd
```

Comment: Please include your entire subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set a well-formed HTML markup. Otherwise, Outlook will not be able to display the message body.

The [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property of the MailItem class returns a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties.  
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 'Create email item  
 Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
 With objMail  
 'Set body format to HTML  
 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML  
 .HTMLBody = _  
 "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"  
 .Display  
 End With  
End Sub
```

If you want to preserve the existing body markup you need to find the closing `</body>` tag 
and insert your piece of HTML markup before the closing tag. And make sure that you end up with a well-formed HTML markup after making any changes.

Finally, you may find the [Working with Outlook HTMLBody – a guide for Office developers](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2015/02/23/outlook-htmlbody-guide/) article helpful.